# remove child from xml by ID / random

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have an XML file like this:

```
<T_Person>
<Person>
 <ID_Person>5B32EB71-E527-482B-B01B-07502D968E70</ID_Person>
 <First_Name_Person>u</First_Name_Person>
</Person>
<Person>
 <ID_Person>C47E80CF-6BDB-49CE-BCF4-20E7E08835BF</ID_Person>
 <First_Name_Person>l</First_Name_Person>
 </Person>
<Person>
 <ID_Person>84E8912E-B8F8-4A94-89D6-21B996C69363</ID_Person>
 <First_Name_Person>n</First_Name_Person>
</Person>
<Person>
 <ID_Person>3DFBDC33-F03E-4579-9D93-256A0FE1BCDA</ID_Person>
 <First_Name_Person>h</First_Name_Person>
</Person>
</T_Person>
```

If I want remove an element by a selected `ID_person`, what should I do?

```
$person = $data->getElementsByTagName('Person')->item(0);
$delete = $data->removeChild($person);
```

If I run that, it will remove the top element. what if I want to remove a random element?

Answer (score 0):

For removing an element by ID:

```
$id = '84E8912E-B8F8-4A94-89D6-21B996C69363';
$people = $data->getElementsByTagName('Person');
$toRemove = null;

foreach ($people as $person) {
    $personId = $person->getElementsByTagName('ID_Person')->item(0)->nodeValue;

    // have to be careful with removeChild in a foreach loop
    if ($personId === $id) {
        $toRemove = $person;
    }
}

if ($toRemove) {    
    $delete = $data->removeChild($toRemove);
}
```

Here's an [example script](http://ideone.com/W4haxt).

For removing a random element, use `rand`:

```
$people = $data->getElementsByTagName('Person');
$person = $people->item(rand(1, $people->length) - 1);
$delete = $data->removeChild($person);
```

Reference: [rand() documentation](http://php.net/rand), [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/domnodelist), [example](http://ideone.com/uSRP4k)

Comment: how is it not working? What does `rand(1, $people->length)` give? Have you seen the example?

Comment: it's still remove the top from my list

Comment: The example doesn't do that. Have you tried running it multiple times? Of course, it's going to remove the first one *some* of the time. http://ideone.com/uSRP4k